# HttpRequestMessage.Method set to Post, but it Gets instead

Tags: c#, .net-core

```
            //request init
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri(client.BaseAddress + ""),
            Content = jsonContent
        };
        Console.WriteLine(request.Method);
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.RequestMessage);
```

[The Request message shows that it was sent as GET, even though I set Method to Post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ5lR.png)

Comment: Is the endpoint you're hitting doing a redirect? maybe from http to https? can you configure the HttpClientHandler to set AllowAutoRedirect to false?

Comment: Can you include the initialization of `client`?  I wouldn't expect it's  doing anything other than `new HttpClient()` but maybe more is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your endpoint is doing a redirect, try turning that off via the HttpClientHandler.

```cs
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

var client = new HttpClient(handler);

// Do your work.
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is doing the right thing. here's a console app that does the same thing, and the outcome is the right one. an Https POST call is done to the configured URL.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace testapicall
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://google.com")
            };

            Console.WriteLine(request.Method);
            var response =  client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine(response.RequestMessage);
            
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the console log output: Method: POST, RequestUri: [https://google.com/'](https://google.com/%27), Version: 1.1, Content: , Headers:{}

what is the resource behind the URL you're trying to call doing? Maybe it is redirecting to another resource, by doing a GET request.

Comment: Problem solved, turns out you can't do a post request using client.BaseAddress as requestUri :D

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use the RestClient to execute the Rest APIs.

Please refer the following URL and sample code
https://restsharp.dev/

```
            var client = new RestClient("URL");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("parameter name", "values");            
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
```

Comment: It's not a RestAPI. I'm scraping a website, and need to POST to a specific endpoint before. Is there a speed difference between HttpClient and RestClient?